# Html link is not clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index

I have a [page with quire simple layout](https://laravel-datagrid.tatrytec.eu/?chgrid-perPage=10). At the end of the page is footer with link. The problem is that link is not clickable. I tried to set z-index: 1000000 for footer element but without success. Dont understand what is the problem. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with that code?

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="xxxxxx.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="main" class="translateInit translate-2 col-12"> 

            @yield('content')

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footerPusher"></div>
</div>    

<div id="footer">
    <strong>Created & designed by <a href="https://tatrytec.eu/blog">Tatrytec.eu</a> 2020</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and scss looks like

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    /* makes footer visible cause 100% push it outside of window */
    margin-bottom: -5em;
}

#main {
    padding-bottom: 10em;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I made an edit with all necessary html and css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to apply a z-index, you need to position the element first, so it isn't static. For example:

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I have checked and `z-index: 1` is enough to make the link clickable. ;)

Comment: Dont understand. I am using z-index many times and dont remember it is related to position. Is there any documetnation to this?

Comment: Sure! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index. You can see the definition says "The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items." By "positioned element" it means an element with any position but static. ;)

Comment: The z-index isn't even needed here. Setting the position alone will fix it

Comment: Thnak you, `position:relative` really works. Dont understand it.....

Answer (score 1):

After checking the link provided, there was a `padding-bottom: 10em;` to the `#main` div. You need to remove it, and

Give a `margin-top: 10em;` to `#footer` div.

That would solve the problem.

Currently the #main div is on top of the footer, that's why it is not clickable.

Comment: While I commend you for wanting to help and solve the problem, pleeeeeease don't answer questions that haven't met the basic requirements of the site. This question hasn't posted a [mcve], so it will have no value to anyone in the future once it's been fixed.

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the reminder, I will keep that in mind. :)

Comment: But element which is last in order of html code should have be above all previouse element. How is it possible that main is above the footer. Thanks for answer. I will use position: relative.

Comment: @Čamo, because the `#main` is `position: relative`, thats why it is coming on top of the footer.